# Writing for multiple resolutions on Android?

Tags: android, resolution, device

I am coding this little game for my Galaxy Nexus using the Canvas/Paint classes. I am also hard coding coordinate values of where to draw stuff.

What happens when I tell an image to display at 500, 760 and on my device its correct, i assume on a smaller resolution device the outcome will not be the same?

How do i go about making sure it looks the same in all resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Density Independent Pixels to define the drawables :dp
For images use density specific resources and put them in appropriate resource folders.

Comment: public static int dp(int value) {
  return (int)(value * PIXEL_DENSITY + 0.5F);
}

not sure what the 0.5F is for. anyway this works kinda, however its slightly off. for example if i spawn something at the end of my device size (galaxy nexus @ 720p) its like this

 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
  lastPoint = new Point();
  lastPoint.x = (int) (float)(event.getX() / PIXEL_DENSITY);
  lastPoint.y = (int) (float)(event.getY() / PIXEL_DENSITY);
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't hard-code the coordinates in pixels. You can use the following:

`getApplicationContext().getDisplayMetrics.density;` //value like 1.00 or 0.75 etc..

If you multiply this by the coordinates in pixels you'll get higher  coordinate values for higher density screens (actually same as dp).

`o